# Find a function based on slope

Tags: calculus, slope

I need to find a function, where I know the slope of the function at any point.

The function is valid when $x$ is between $-1$ and $1$ including the $1$ and $-1$.
The slope is equal to $|1 - x|$.
The value of the function at $x = -1$ is $0$.
The value of the function at $x = 1$ is $1$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Perhaps integration might help?